# Can't click to Customize link when div+link together with FakeAnchor class using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can't click to Customize link when div+link together with FakeAnchor class using selenium web driver

In my Ajax application, we have dropdown + link (Customize) together in div and i want to click to Customize link. I have locator and which was working fine for Customize link with old selenium but it doesn't with latest web driver. Can anyone please point me the problem or suggest something to make it work?

## Expected:

> Clicking to Customize link should open respected option (it actually opens dialog).

## Actual:

> Below locator clicks to dropdown button instead of Customize link due to such a complex page DOM which has no actual href or anchor tag.

## Locator:

```
css=div[id$='_repeatDesc'][class='FakeAnchor']
```

## Html:

```
<div id="zcs1_repeatDesc" class="FakeAnchor" style="cursor: pointer;">Customize</div>
```

## Code:

```
webDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id$='_repeatDesc'][class='FakeAnchor']")).click();
```

[image: UI element and DOM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your locator is not unique, may be it is locating dropdown element that's why it clicks to dropdown button instead of Customize link.

You should try using `By.xpath()` with `text()` node to locate this element as below :-

```
webDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//div[text() = 'Customize']")).click();
```

Or As I'm seeing in HTML element has `id` attribute, if it's unique I'd to locate desire element and it's not being changed dynamically, you can try also using `By.id()` as below :-

```
webDriver().findElement(By.id("zcs1_repeatDesc")).click();
```

**Edited** :- If you want to click using `JavascriptExecutor` try as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//div[text() = 'Customize']")));
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh! I'm accepting this as helpful but sorry to say, it doesn't work. Is there any way using Javascript executor to click to Customize link?

Comment: @Jits Ok see edited answer to perform click using `JavascriptExecutor`. Try it and let me know

Comment: JavascriptExecutor worked, please accept the question. Thanks again!